# in app link to app store app

Tags: iphone, hyperlink, app-store, rate

Just trying to make a button that links in ratings tab in app store but have some problems doing so, found lot of links with itms:// and http:// as prefix but non of them work in simulator could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simulator has no app store; none of them will work.

You want a link like this:

- http://www.itunes.com/app/[appname]

That'll work on the device, but not the simulator. There's another variation that lets you specify the company name, too. The link will go to Safari first, which will a moment later open App Store without the user needing to do anything.

*Source: [Technical Q&A QA1633 Creating easy-to-read links to the App Store for your applications and company](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1633/_index.html)*

You can try using a itms+apps style link, like this:

- itms+apps://www.itunes.com/app/[appname]

This will skip launching Safari first, and just go straight to App Store. While this currently works, I'm not sure it's documented anywhere. I plan on trying this, and I'll update this answer later if I'm approved.

Comment: okey and that will open the app store or the safari in the iphone? thanks for your fast answer...

Comment: It opens Safari, then Safari opens App Store with no user action required.

Comment: one more question if there are more than one apps with the same name worldwide then which app is it gonna load? and how can i get the link i want!

Comment: You probably want to include the company name, then. I found the relevant developer docs and will update my answer to include it. It's short and answers all of this and more. :)

Comment: If you use the version I mentioned, it will open the App Store directly without going through Safari first.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is a link directly to the **Reviews** section for your app's App Store page, you want something like this (replace the id parameter with your own):

itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=393783219&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software

For the main App Store page, use:

http://itunes.apple.com/app/id393783219

And like Steven Fisher said, it won't work on the Simulator.

Comment: Yup. <random text to get to the minimum number of caracters needed to enter a comment>

Comment: Yeah, this'll work. It isn't the current recommendation, though. :)

Comment: Hm well, regarding iPad: the link works (i.e. I just tried it now on my iPad and it did open the review page) - but I remember reading something about reviews not working properly on iPads (i.e. due to a bug by Apple) for a while now... so even if the link works, I'm not 100% sure that reviews on iPads are working.

Comment: yeah thanks for trying i've read so too that's why i've asked!